# Mathematical notation for vector variation

Tags: notation, vectors, machine-learning

Could someone help me mathematically describe the following problem.

I have a vector $X = [x_1, ..., x_n]^T$ that represents a list of features. I also have a prediction function $p$ so that $p(X) = \lambda$ where $\lambda$ is the predicted class.

I have another vector $E = [\varepsilon_1, ..., \varepsilon_n]^T$ that contains the importance value of each corresponding feature of $X$.

What I'm trying to mathematically describe is that: if I generate a new duplicate vector $X^*$ that only keeps intact the features of $X$ that have the highest importance values in $E$, and randomly vary (i.e. add noise to) the remaining features (i.e. the ones that have low importance values), I should still observe that $p(X) = \lambda = p(X^*).$

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Sounds a little bit like dimension reduction techniques such as Principal Components Analysis. Do you have to vary the unimportant features, or could you just drop them altogether?

Comment: @AdrianKeister It does sound a bit like PCA, but I need to vary the unimportant features to show that whatever value they take, they will not affect the prediction.

Comment: Very well. You don't think you've described it enough already?

Comment: @AdrianKeister I'm not sure what you mean. I need to formulate that process mathematically...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the details I could think to add might look like this:

1. Choose a $\varepsilon_{\text{cutoff}}$ that represents the cut-off importance: importances above this you'll keep, and those below you'll vary.
2. Choose your $X^*=[x_1^*, x_2^*,\dots,x_n^*]^T$ as follows: 
   $$x_j^*=\begin{cases}x_j,\quad& \varepsilon_j\ge\varepsilon_{\text{cutoff}} \\
   x_j+\theta_j, & \varepsilon_j<\varepsilon_{\text{cutoff}}\end{cases}. $$
   Here $\theta_j$ is a random noise function, such as a Gaussian or (probably better) from a suitably chosen uniform distribution.
3. Evaluate $p(X^*)$ and check that your model predicts the same class as $p(X)$ does.
4. Repeat Steps 1-3 until you are satisfied that the new restricted features correctly predict the output class $\lambda$ regardless of whatever noise you introduce in the less important features.